# Android Error on writing file to sd card : Open Failed eacces permission denied

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

I want to write an image file to sd card, but i get an error :**Open Failed eacces permission denied**.

i am using this code:

```
File ff = new File("/storage/sdcard1/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0258.JPG");
try{ 
    ff.createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e){ 
    Log.d("error" , "creating");
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

I have added permission :-

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I am not using android 6.0 , so permission is not required at run time.

The same code works fine when file path changed to internal storage path.

but still getting error.

Comment: I think you added the permission in the wrong place
make sure it's in the <manifest> tag and outside <application> tag

Comment: Yes, Its at correct position. Outside application tag

Answer (score 1):

First, few Android devices will have such a path.

Second, you do not have arbitrary read-write access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4 and higher.

If you want to give users the option of working with removable storage, use [the Storage Access Framework APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) on Android 4.4+.

Comment: this path I get using getExternalStorage code. And other than Android 4.4 I want to write to sd card

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria: "this path I get using getExternalStorage code" -- then your question should show this code, not some hardcoded string. We cannot help you with code that is not in the question. "And other than Android 4.4 I want to write to sd card" -- [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). There is no official support for removable storage prior to Android 4.4.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But then i think how file manager application read sd card and how can they add,rename,delete files.

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria: They use undocumented and unsupported techniques that, as a result, fail to work on some devices.

Comment: I am now using SAF for Sd Card writting, but getting error. Please help me with SAF. Really stuck at this. I have posted my issue in new question . Link :-   http://stackoverflow.com/q/38998276/5309039