# Get Persistable SD Cad write Permission using SAF

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard, filewriter, storage-access-framework

In my application, list of Image files is inflated in recyclerview. Then after application edits the metadata of Image file.

My code for writing metadata:-

```
DocumentFile fos = DocumentFile.fromFile(new File(fileIn));

ByteSource bytsInputStream = new ByteSourceFile(new File(fileIn));
byte[] byteArrayInputStream = bytsInputStream.getAll();

try {
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().
            openFileDescriptor(fos.getUri(), "w");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
            new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

    rewriter.updateExifMetadataLossy(byteArrayInputStream,fileOutputStream,outputSet);

    fileOutputStream.close();
    pfd.close();

}
catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

I am able to update image file stored in phone memory, but for the Sd Card Images, I get error ---->

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
```

I know that from android 5 , we need to take permission using SAF. 
My code for taking permission:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);












@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri treeUri = data.getData();
                int takeFlags = data.getFlags();
                takeFlags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                              Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    this.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);
                }
           }
    }
```

Now I dont know what to do with this treeUri.
I want that I take SdCard Permission Once at initial startup only.

**In simple terms my question relates to this question:-**

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39054454/5309039)

Answer (score 1):

```
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
```

here treeUri is what you get from SAF permission. Means what you get in  OnActivityResult().

> DocumentFile fos = DocumentFile.fromFile(new File(fileIn));

In this, fileIn is your selected file. then

```
String[] parts = (fileIn.getPath()).split("\\/");
for (int i = 3; i < parts.length; i++) {
if (documentFile != null) {
    documentFile = documentFile.findFile(parts[i]);
}  
}
```

hereafter for getting byteArray you need to use this code

```
try {
                        InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(documentFile.getUri());
                        byte[] byteArrayInputStream = getBytes(iStream);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

After getting byte array you want to continue your code, and also i metion below.

```
try {
                        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fos.getUri(), "w");
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
                        rewriter.updateExifMetadataLossy(byteArrayInputStream,fileOutputStream,outputSet);
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                        pfd.close();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

> Not: I think this will help you. If you find any mistakes please correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Saving the Uri with

```
takePersistableUriPermission()
```

is absolutely right to gain access. The permission is kept until uninstalling or clearing app data.
Next step is to keep the Uri for later access (i.e. SharedPreferences).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop) will help you.

Comment: But what to do after storing Uri in sharedPreferences. As described in my question I want to edit an existing document. So how to use the Uri in accessing this particular file

Comment: Map the Uri path to a File path. That way you can access the files under the path with granted permissions: getFullPathFromTreeUri() [link](https://github.com/jeisfeld/Augendiagnose/blob/7e09f12cec5921b65541d28bd11caa6ce8d96e53/AugendiagnoseIdea/augendiagnoseLib/src/main/java/de/jeisfeld/augendiagnoselib/util/imagefile/FileUtil.java#L774)

Comment: Not able to get your point. Please help me in this question:- http://stackoverflow.com/q/39054454/5309039

Comment: It has an active bounty also. Please help me with solution. Really in need of help for SAF editing